# Python Turtle Module - Creating a flag

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create a flag in turtle module with a square bounded by points (-200,-200), (0,-200), (0,0) and (-200, 0). 
Then I want to set up the width paramater to be at random in (100,200). However, I'm stuck on this and don't know how to proceed.

```
import turtle 
import random

tina = turtle.Turtle()

tina.color('blue')

tina.begin_fill()
tina.goto(-200,-200)
tina.goto(0, -200)
tina.goto(0,0)
tina.goto(-200,0)
tina.goto(200,-200)

tina.end_fill()
turtle.exitonclick()
```

Comment: What is it that you are stuck on?

Comment: Stuck on preventing the drawing from going off turtle screen window.

Comment: There's no mention of that in your question. Next time, go over [ask].

Comment: Well, it wasn't my original problem. My original problem was what I asked as my question. cdlane answered my question, and I was able to set the proper boundaries to get my code working (which I gladly shared). Now, this is a separate issue. I figured maybe someone would answer it in the comments , so I don't have to create a new question. Thank you so much for leaving a link on "how to ask". I really appreciate it

Comment: If you have a separate question about something, just write a separate question. An important thing to understand about [SO] is that its key goal is to collect useful questions and answers that can help others. The fact that it answers someone's particular question is a (really nice) side effect but the main thing is being a repository of info useful to other readers. Which is why the clarity and quality of both questions and answers matter and why there are seemingly endless pages of guidelines and rules in [help].

Answer (score 0):

Your square code was close, you just rounded the bases in the wrong order and had an extra `.goto()` you didn't need.  I believe the following does what you describe:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
import random

screen = Screen()
tina = Turtle()  # starts at (0, 0)
tina.color('blue')

tina.begin_fill()
tina.goto(0, -200)
tina.goto(-200, -200)
tina.goto(-200, 0)
tina.goto(0, 0)
tina.end_fill()

tina.width(random.randint(100, 200))

# ... continue drawing

screen.exitonclick()
```

Note that 100 - 200 is an awfully wide pen, 1 - 20 is more typical.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer helped me figure out how to set up boundary, so I could create my flag

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, my answer was wrong. It wasn't exactly what I was trying to do. I had to set up the boundary so the random flag only exists within the third quadrant. Here's how I fixed it: 
from random import *
from turtle import *

```
def maritime():

  # allows you to color the square blue
  color('blue')
  shape('turtle')
  # declare a random integer within the boundary between -200 and 200
  x = randint(-200,0)
  y = randint(-200,0 )
  # declare a random integer with the boundary between 100 and 200
  width = randint(100, 200)



 # Lines 16 -27 allow you to create a filled blue square
 penup()
 setposition(x, y)
 pendown()
 begin_fill()
 left(90)
 forward(width)
 left(90)
 forward(width)
 left(90)
 forward(width)
 left(90)
 forward(width)
 penup()
 # makes the square proportional to the larger square
 goto(x - width/3.64, y + width/3.64)
 pendown()

 # Lines 35-42 allows you to create the smaller square
 left(90)
 forward(width/2)
 left(90)
 forward(width/2)
 left(90)
 forward(width/2)
 left(90)
 forward(width/2)
 end_fill()
 penup()
 setposition(x, y + width)
 pendown()

 # Lines 49-60 allows you to create a filled red vertical rectangle
 color("red")
 begin_fill()
 for count in range(2):
forward(50)
right(90)
forward(width)
right(90)
end_fill()
penup()
forward(100)
pendown()

# Lines 63-37 allow you to create a filled blue verticle rectangle
begin_fill()
color("blue")
for count in range(2):
   forward(50)
   right(90)
   forward(width)
   right(90)
end_fill()

back(100)
color("black")
for i in range(2):
   forward(150)
   right(90)
   forward(width)
   right(90)

 speed(20)
 hideturtle()
 exitonclick() # allows the user to exit turtle screen with a click
 print (maritime())
```